Riverpod: Integrating a Single Endpoint Across Multiple Stepper Screens in Flutter + Riverpod
Question:
I'm building a Flutter application with a stepper wizard, consisting of 4-5 separate screens (each in its own file). Each screen contains various form fields (text fields, dropdowns, date pickers, etc.). I need to integrate a single endpoint to add applicants, submitting data from all screens.
Requirements:

Integrate a single endpoint across multiple screens.
Handle form data from each screen.
Submit combined data to the endpoint.

Current Implementation:

Each screen is a separate widget.
Stepper widget calls each screen sequentially.
Endpoint is a POST request to add applicants.

Code Snippet:
// Stepper widget
Stepper(
  steps: [
    Screen1(),
    Screen2(),
    // ...
  ],
)

Screen1.dart (example)
class Screen1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        TextField(
          // ...
        ),
        DropdownButton(
          // ...
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

Screen2.dart (example)
class Screen2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        TextField(
          // ...
        ),
        DropdownButton(
          // ...
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

Endpoint (example)
Future<void> addApplicant(ApplicantData data) async {
  // POST request to endpoint
}

How can I integrate the endpoint across multiple screens, combining data from each screen?

Your title mentions riverpod. Have you tried defining a notifier/provider and converting your widgets to ConsumerWidget or StatefulConsumerWidget? Is there a particular area you are struggling with?

@DanR yes, i have but the code is too long that's why i was unable to add,, maybe we can do this team viewer

You need a riverpod service that holds the aggregated model data representing the answers for all screens, and some sentinel (either null or the None() from Option()) to indicate a field is not complete yet.  Each screen will call the mutation method for its portion of the form data.  The final screen will submit it to the server.
